# How do I add two variables together and store the result into another variable?

Tags: tcl

I can't figure out the most basic Tcl syntax, what is the right way to write the following:

```
set var1 5
set var2 3
set var3 $var1 - $var2; # error line

puts $var3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tcl has no syntax for math operations. Instead it relies on the `expr` command/function to do math:

```
set var3 [expr $var1 - $var2]
```

Best practice is to supply only a single argument to `expr` quoted by braces to avoid subtle issues like double substitution:

```
set var3 [expr {$var1 - $var2}]
```

Comment: Thanks. It is super odd that a scripting language takes this much work for something so simple (compared to C), although I do appreciate string interpolation.

Comment: @AndrejM. It takes really little work once you get used to it :) And you don't need to put `;` after almost every line, if that's not enough of a compensation!

Comment: There's more to languages than a simple scripting/compiled divide. Indeed C is also a scripting language since there is an implementation of a C interpreter that can run C programs without being compiled but Java is a language that requires a compiler even though it is a language that must run on an interpreter (VM). Tcl belongs to a family of languages with minimal syntax like Forth and Lisp where the language can't do math as part of the syntax but rather uses functions to do all the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 4):

In Tcl, you need the function [`expr`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/583) for evaluations:

```
set var3 [expr {$var1 - $var2}]
```

You can however skip them in Tcl 8.5+ when you are dealing with indices, for example:

```
% set numberlist [list 1 2 3 4]
% set index 2
% puts [lindex $numberlist $index-1]
2
```

Otherwise in older versions, you'd have to use `expr` again:

```
% set numberlist [list 1 2 3 4]
% set index 2
% puts [lindex $numberlist [expr {$index-1}]]
2
```

It's good practice to put braces in your [`expr`essions](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10225), though you don't *have to*.

Comment: For the second, you can use `incr` if you prefer that over `expr`.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/tclintro.doc.html

http://www.astro.princeton.edu/~rhl/Tcl-Tk_docs/tcl/expr.n.html

Try

set var3 [expr $var1 - $var2]

Comment: You forgot the square brackets

Comment: Yeah, it's too early and TCL was too long ago. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since Tcl 8.5, the math operators and functions are also available as commands. Check [the examples section of the mathop manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/mathop.htm#M32) for an alternative to `expr`.